# PHP Illegal array key type warning (PHPStorm)

Tags: php, arrays, types, key

[Here is my example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XL7PX.jpg)

It actually works on server but I wonder why do I get this warning?
Thanks

Comment: It's telling you this because you're deviding a value lets say `$koortAdt = 3` it will get divided by two. Making it `$koordAll[1.5 + 1]` and a array key cannot be a floating value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use float number as array index.

To change floats to integer use function like [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

Comment: Side note: it is faster to use `(int)` instead of `intval`